# How do I prevent VNC from automatically coping selected text?

Tags: vnc, copy-paste, realvnc

Whenever I select any text the text is immediately copied to the clipboard without me explicitly issuing copy text command. How do I fix this bug or feature?

I am using RealVNC client. The server is running IceWM.

Comment: And you're also using the RealVNC server (just called "VNC Server") right? I am seeing the same issue, it's very annoying. I am using the official free RealVNC client and server. Also, since this is a very old question -- did you ever figure out a fix?

Comment: @Ricket No I was not using RealVNC server. When I use that then _mostly_ it works, not always. RealVNC Server+Client, sometimes the copy and paste stops working absolutely. Then I go back to old non-RealVNC Server and it works.

Comment: I am also having the same issue, very annoying and slows down my work! Just in case if you find a fix, please post it here!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open `~/.vnc/xstartup`
2. Change the **vncconfig** line to include `SendPrimary=0 (e.g. vncconfig SendPrimary=0 –nowin &)`
3. Restart your VNC sessions

**How it works:**

- `vncconfig` is a program that manages shared functionality between the x11 server and your VNC session, most notably shared clipboard functionality. Without this running in the background, you cannot share a clipboard.
- X11 maintains a concept of a “primary” buffer (for selected text) and a “clipboard” buffer
- **SendPrimary** defaults to `1` (on) which instructs `vncconfig` to send the primary (selection) buffer to the clipboard buffer, in effect overwriting anything there

Comment: This options seems to have disappeared in latest version. Is there a workaround?